# Jest test sometimes fails (DynamoDB integration tests)

Tags: docker, jestjs, amazon-dynamodb, integration-testing, bitbucket-pipelines

I have Serverless application (node:14.19.1-bullseye-slim) with almost 400 tests. There are mostly functional tests with using of [local DynamoDb](https://hub.docker.com/r/amazon/dynamodb-local). The problem is Bitbucket pipeline sometimes fail with message:

```
thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 10000 ms for a test.
Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."
```

The bad thing of this the issue that is not reproducible on local machine. It's green in 9/10 runs. Also on Bitbucket pipeline not every run fails and not in the same test suite.

## Here is my configuration:

**package.json**

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-lambda": "3.58.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "3.58.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-ssm": "3.58.0",
    "@aws-sdk/node-http-handler": "3.58.0",
    "@fast-csv/format": "4.3.5",
    "aws-sdk": "2.1001.0",
    "axios-curlirize": "1.3.7",
    "axios-mock-adapter": "1.20.0",
    "chalk": "4.1.2",
    "eslint": "8.12.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb-base": "15.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "2.25.4",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "26.1.3",
    "ion-js": "4.2.2",
    "jest": "27.5.1",
    "jest-junit": "13.0.0",
    "js-yaml": "4.1.0",
    "jsbi": "4.2.0",
    "prettier": "2.6.1"
    },
"scripts": {
    "ci": "npx jest --coverage --colors --ci"
}
```

**jest.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    collectCoverageFrom: [
        'src/**',
    ],
    coverageReporters: [
        'text',
        'html',
    ],
    maxWorkers: 1,
    testEnvironment: 'node',
    testTimeout: 10000,
    verbose: true,
};
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
dynamo:
    image: amazon/dynamodb-local:1.18.0
    command: '-jar DynamoDBLocal.jar -inMemory -sharedDb'
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

## More logs didn't help

I tried to get more information about failing test. I prepared "custom" [DynamoDB docker image](https://github.com/wernerwws/dynamodb-local-with-logging) and turned-on AWS-SDK logs but it didn't help me a lot. I also tried latest LTS version of Node and AWS-SDK. I also found Jest [issue](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11607) and tried "guaranteed workarounds" but without chance.

## Questions

1. Does someone resolved similar problem?
2. What I can do more for finding the problem?

The last thing what I have is rewrite tests to not directly using of dockerized DynamoDB but this will be the last try.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the problem is not on any DynamoDB side.

I have made some research on the problem and found the next thread with a discussion of the error like you. And the error has been appeared after upgrading jest to v.27

https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/11607

They have assumptions about some bugs in the jest timer. So the solutions can be is:

1. to increase the timer value above 10 000.
2. or use jest.useFakeTimers('legacy') setting if possible.
3. if applicable switch the jest version back to v26.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Jest is configured correctly there could be a few reasons why this is happening:

- Stateful tests whereby the order of the tests matters, and tests are not being executed in the same order each time, or between runs tables have changed
- Throughput Capacity problems, as many tests are executed in a very quick manor this may mean that your table does not have enough WCU RCU to handle the requests
- Tables not being cleaned correctly before each run

I have had a lot of problems when running tests with DynamoDB because I'd typically be using a test Table which is not provisioned with a high capacity because it is not needed normally. But when you run many tests really quickly even if it is only on your machine this can happen.